# I have accidentally deleted the mac default sound driver and now I can not use my default speaker and microphone

Tags: mac, audio, drivers, microphone

Can someone please send me a copy of the default sound folder?

I believe it is in the folder `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL`
What I currently have is this:
[image: a picture of my HAL folder previously mentioned]

My current Sound Output and Sound Input, and it is missing the default

[image: Sound Output]

[image: Sound Input]

Can someone help me identify which driver im missing and perhaps a copy of it?

Comment: Kindly check if this similar thread from Apple support can help you: [accidentally deleted soundcard drivers,built in audio disappeared.how to install again?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6825649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check in Apps/Utilities/Audio Midi Setup & post a pic of your Audio setup page, just for confirmation.
Then boot to Recovery ( <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at boot) & re-install the OS. If you do this directly from the onboard recovery straight over the existing OS it will not affect your data, though you should always have a backup anyway.

That should reinstate any missing or corrupted Apple components.
I think you're missing the BridgeAudioSP.driver. The reinstall should put it back.

Comment: Ok That worked. Many Thanks!@Tetsujin